# JasperReports. Wrong layout in generated PDF report with two tables

Tags: jasper-reports

During PDf generation in Jasper, I have 2 bands having table in each, if data display of table1 ends in 90% of a page in PDF, then data display of table 2 display starts, where the table column header cannot be able to print within that page, so it prints only the border line of the table in that balance 10% of the page, but it normally prints the same data in next page. Here the problem is, it should not print the border of the table in first page if the actual data containing in that table cell cant able to print it within that page. This looks like some junk printing in the PDF. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the group which holds Table 2, set the **minHeightToStartNewPage**, as per your requirements (maybe something like 100 or 200, for an A4 layout).